# How do I set Vim mapleader to <Tab>?

Tags: vim

I tried

```
let mapleader = "<Tab>"
```

and

```
let mapleader = "Tab"
```

but neither worked. Right now instead of having

```
nnoremap <Leader>whatever ...<CR>
```

I have

```
nnoremap <Tab>whatever ...<CR>
```

But I would really like to use `<Leader>`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
:let mapleader = "\<tab>"
```

See:

```
:help expr-quote
```

Specifically the end of the table in the help entry.